# onclick event not working in firefox but works fine in IE

Tags: javascript

I got a simple form and it works fine in ie but not working in firefox

```
onclick="login('loginuser','../private/loginuser.php?username='+email.value+'&pass='+passw.value,'loginresult');"
```

Any help appreciated.

Comment: What are `email` and `passw`?

Comment: Can you try changing `&pass` to `&amp;pass`? And can you give more details on how it doesn't "work"?

Answer (score 1):

You should start by putting some alert calls in your login function to make sure that your arguments are getting quoted properly.  Something like

```
function login (username, password, result) {
  alert(username);
  alert(password);
  alert(result);
  .... rest of function

}
```

Answer (score 0):

That's not really a form, just an attribute snippet. Install Firebug add-on for Firefox (https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/1843/) and eliminate the guesswork by debugging the javascript. You can set a breakpoint in your login() function and see if everything is ok there or if at least if it gets called.